# Emails stopped arriving - no coding change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, visual-studio-2015, smtpclient

I have code that has been successfully sending emails for three years. As of a week ago these emails fail to arrive. I was wondering whether AVG was causing the problem or McFee WebProtector.

I have supplied the code below just so you can see my method.

web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="FromAddress" value="webmaster@mydomain.com" />
<add key="FromName" value="My Domain Website" />
<add key="ToAddress" value="webmaster@mydomain.com" />
<add key="ToName" value="Web Master" />
<add key="SendMailOnError" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Web Master &lt;me@btinternet.com&gt;">
    <network host="mail.btinternet.com" userName="me@btinternet.com" password="NinaDobreva" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

web

```
Dim fileName As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ContactForm.txt")
        Dim mailBody As String = File.ReadAllText(fileName)

        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", Name.Text)
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", EmailAddress.Text)
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##HomePhone##", PhoneHome.Text)
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##BusinessPhone##", PhoneBusiness.Text)
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Comments##", Comments.Text)

        Dim myMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
        myMessage.Subject = "Response from Website Contact Form"
        myMessage.Body = mailBody
        myMessage.From = New MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("FromAddress").ToString, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("FromName").ToString)
        myMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("ToAddress").ToString, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("ToName").ToString))

        Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
        Try
            mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage)
            Message.Text = "Thank you. Your message has been sent."
        Catch
            lblResult.Text = "Transmission error, please try again."
            lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Message.Text = "Error sending message. Message not sent."
        End Try

    Else
        lblResult.Text = "Incorrect, please try again."
        lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        Message.Text = "Message not sent."
    End If
```

Running it in debug it executes the mySmtpClient.Send statement ok. Is there anyway I can track what happens after this?

I've manually (via outlook) sent emails to the same email addresses to check they are all still working, which they are. And I've also checked all the junk folders etc.

But as all this has been working (since last Tuesday) it makes me think it must be some non code issue? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your lblResult have your error message in it ? Can you append the error message you are catching that makes it show up ?

Comment: Have you tried manually sending an email from the account/server you are using to send these emails? Since `smtp.send` returns a null you just have to assume it was sent to the server and queued up. At this point you will not know unless you get an exception. The only other way is to be able to check the server...

Comment: If the email for some reason or another gets rejected you should most definitely get a response code and description of the problem.

Comment: Also is there a reason you would be using your default ISP email server to send these. Usually for sending out emails you would get an account that is used for this purpose...

Comment: I would highly suggest subscribing to SendCompleted, use the example below to see if there are errors.

http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.6.aspx

Comment: Someone that matters thanks for looking into this - lblResult has no error as no error is occurring hence no error message is being caught. I've manually sent emails to the email addresses and the emails arrive ok.

Comment: Codexer - thanks for input. I've manually sent emails to the email addresses and the emails arrive ok. The email server shows no e-mails waiting to be sent - or having arrived.

Comment: Codexer: I use the default ISP email server just because it works. I will eventually change this when the site goes live.

Comment: Karen - Thanks I'll try that and let you know what happens.

Comment: Can you try to use this same code to send email through another email address/host? I would guess that either a system update or security feature is breaking your code.

Comment: Karen - I used a SendAsync to use SendCompleted and it crashed. I then ran again with my Send and it worked as usual But emails have started arriving again. I can only assume the SendAsync even though it crashed cleared out some gunge - technical term ; - in VisualStudio but whatever the reason the emails are arriving again. I'm writing a module using your SendCompleted idea as I need to ensure that the send is completed. So thanks for your help.

Comment: ChicagoMike - good idea. I'm setting up my config file so that I have a choice of email address/host so if I have any other problems I can always switch to see if the host is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Karen Payne's suggestion led to the problem going away and is a good practice. See below.

I would highly suggest subscribing to SendCompleted, use the example below to see if there are errors. systemnetmail.com/faq/4.6.aspx – Karen Payne yesterday